# Insert into SQL database using Python

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, websocket, raspberry-pi

I want to put a value from my Raspberry Pi into a SQL database on my laptop by using websocket in a Python script.

```
#starting import MySQLdb

import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","cms",autocommit=True)

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

from websocket import create_connection

ws = create_connection("ws://192.168.0.53:8080/websocket")

while True:
    result = ws.recv()
    print(result)
    spl = result.split(' ',1)
    boom_id2 = str(spl[0])
    boom_data = str(spl[1])



    sql = """INSERT INTO datain(boom_id2,boom_data)
             # VALUES ('""" + boom_id2 +"""', '""" + boom_data +"""')"""
    cursor.execute(sql)


db.close()
ws.close()
```

It returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Ashraff\Desktop\Enginnering\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\Ashraff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\Ashraff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\Ashraff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\Ashraff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Ashraff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Ashraff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2")
```

Comment: issue in the sql syntax.

Comment: _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2")

Comment: try to debug the code and put a break point after it makes the whole query and just before executing the query, take the value of query and try to run it on MySQL, you'll get to know the error. or paste the complete sql query here we will try to help.

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your SQL query
it should be something like this

```
   sql = ("""INSERT INTO datain(boom_id2,boom_data)
            VALUES (%s, %s)""", (boom_id2, boom_data))
   print(sql)
   cursor.execute(sql)
```

try to print this SQL query and run it in your local server to check whether your query is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

```
def insert_data(lVideoList, gate_id):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite',
                                 detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES |
                                              sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    success = 200
##    gateid = 1
    default_value = 0
    for gate_id in range(no_of_gate):
        gate_id = i+1
        for videofilename in lVideoList:
            print("videofilename: ", videofilename)
            insert_query = ("INSERT INTO dailyfootfall(csv_name, video_download, processed, footfall, send_status, "
                            "male_footfall, send_status_male, female_footfall, send_status_female, gate_id,outsiders, send_status_outsiders) "
                            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)")
            
            cursor.execute(insert_query,[videofilename, success, success, default_value, success, default_value,
                                        success, default_value, success, gate_id, default_value, success])

       
    print("Data Inserted Successfully !")
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    lVideoList = getCompleteVideoList("2022_01_24", "10:00", "22:00")
    no_of_gate = 3
    insert_data (lVideoList, gate_id)
    print("default_value inserted!!!!")
```